# Background processing works in Simulator but not on a real device

Tags: background, ios8, device

I am creating an iOS8 app that records audio. The app allows users to set up a daily schedule to record (i.e., start time and duration). This works fine in the simulator. For example, suppose the schedule is to start recording at 11pm for 8 hours. I start the app at 10:30pm and hit the Home button to simulate the background processing. The app would start recording at 11pm and record for 8 hours. However, after I deploy the app to an iPad 2 (as part of the prerelease testing), the above procedure results in no recording. However, if I leave the app on, it actually starts recording. But as soon as I hit the Home button, it stops recording. It seems that the background processing is not working on the real device.

Is there a configuration I need to set on the real device for this to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We have a similar problem.